# Coverity Scan upload failed: We're sorry, we have recently redesigned our website, and the page you are looking for no longer exists on Coverity Scan

Tags: coverity

I am following [the guide](https://scan.coverity.com/travis_ci) to set up Coverity Scan upload from Travis CI.

In [my build](https://travis-ci.org/msgqe/travisci/builds/222073108) I get the following error (see the log)

```
Successfully added SCM data for 2537 files
[33;1mTarring Coverity Scan Analysis results...[0m
[33;1mUploading Coverity Scan Analysis results...[0m
[33;1mCoverity Scan upload failed: 
000

000



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Coverity Scan - Static Analysis</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

...

<p>
We're sorry, we have recently redesigned our website, and the page you are looking for no longer exists on Coverity Scan.
</p>

<p>
<a href="/">Click here</a> to be redirected to our the Coverity Scan home page.
</p>

...
```

What is the cause of this issue and what can I do to resolve it?

My `.travis.yml` is at https://github.com/msgqe/travisci/blob/activemq-artemis-coverity/.travis.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by changing project name on Coverity. I've registered the project manually, not by importing from GitHub. That meant I could have spaces in my project name. Github imports never do. When I removed spaces from project name, the build imported correctly.

Looking at various Coverity import scripts in the wild[1], there aren't quotes around project name in the last curl command. I believe this is the cause.

[1] https://github.com/DmitriBoulanger/samples-spring-boot/blob/bcee9dcbd6d0d2cfe97186bc2ada05bf311e8804/spring-boot-DOCKER/spring-boot-DOCKER-2/.travis/travisci_build_coverity_scan.sh